# Exporting OpenXML created Excel Spreadsheet to client side

Tags: c#, .net, excel, api, openxml

I am trying to get the API to start a download of the excel spreadsheet that has been created. Although, i seem to be running into some hassle. I have tried to also send the Byte array of the Spreadsheets memory stream through to the front-end and go from there, but the excel file is corrupt and does not contain any data.

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("CreateExcelDocument")]
    public ActionResult CreateExcelDocument([FromBody] List<BarBillList> model)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] tmp;
            using (ExcelController ex = new ExcelController())
            {
                tmp = ex.createExcelSpreadsheet(barBillExport);
            }

            string fileName = "xxx.xlsx";
            return File(tmp, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", fileName);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

ExcelController class with the spreadsheet creation method:

```
 public byte[] createExcelSpreadsheet(List<BarBillList> barBillExport)
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(ms, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
            {
                //Creating the initial document
                WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.AddWorkbookPart();
                workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

                WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet();

                workbookPart.Workbook.Save();

                //Styling the doucment
                WorkbookStylesPart stylesPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
                stylesPart.Stylesheet = GenerateStyleSheet();
                stylesPart.Stylesheet.Save();

                //Adding width to the columns
                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Columns columns = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Columns();
                columns.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Column() { Min = 1, Max = 6, Width = 20, CustomWidth = true });
                worksheetPart.Worksheet.Append(columns);

                //Creating the worksheet part to add the data to
                Sheets sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());
                Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = "BarBill" };
                sheets.Append(sheet);

                SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(new SheetData());

                //Creating the first Header Row
                Row row = new Row();
                row.Append(
                    ConstructCell("Name", CellValues.String, true),
                    ConstructCell("Last Payment Date", CellValues.String, true),
                    ConstructCell("Last Payment Amount", CellValues.String, true),
                    ConstructCell("Current Balance", CellValues.String, true));

                sheetData.AppendChild(row);

                //Appending the data into their respective columns 
                foreach (var ent in barBillExport)
                {
                    row = new Row();

                    row.Append(
                        ConstructCell(ent.Name.ToString(), CellValues.String, false),
                        ConstructCell((ent.LastPaymentDate.ToString().Length > 0) ? ent.LastPaymentDate.ToString() : "", CellValues.String, false),
                        ConstructCell((ent.LastPayment.ToString().Length > 0) ? ent.LastPayment.ToString() : "", CellValues.String, false),
                        ConstructCell((ent.TotalBalance.ToString().Length > 0) ? ent.TotalBalance.ToString() : "", CellValues.String, false));
                    sheetData.AppendChild(row);
                }

                worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

EDIT

Front End Service:

```
    createExcelDocument(model: BillList[]): any {
    return this.http.post(this.getBarBillsUrl + "/CreateExcelDocument", model)
        .map(this.helper.extractData)
        .catch(this.helper.handleError);
}
```

I am aware that the mapper does not need to be there. But im keeping it there should i need to bring the byte array through to the front and go from there.

Any direction or guidance on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

**Solution Found for those interested or facing a similar issue(Please see below answers for author)**

I added the `{ responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob }` to the service call in TypeScript.

It then returned me a blob of the spreadsheet. From there, within the typescript i ran it through another method:

```
    private saveAsBlob(data: any) {
    const year = this.today.getFullYear();
    const month = this.today.getMonth();
    const date = this.today.getDate();
    const dateString = year + '-' + month + '-' + date;

    const file = new File([data], 'BarBill ' + dateString + '.xlsx',
        { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });

    FileSaver.saveAs(file);
}
```

To then get my file to download client side.

Thanks very much to all. Especially the author of the answer.

Comment: what is your front framework? angular ? react ? etc?

Comment: @SiavashGhanbari Currently it is Angular with Typescript.

Comment: I replied the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52667543/1404642 , let me now if is any problem yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell Angular that the response is not JSON format , and so it will not try to parse it. Try changing your code to:

```
  createExcelDocument(model: BillList[]): any {
    return this.http.post(this.getBarBillsUrl + "/CreateExcelDocument", 
            model,  { responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob })
        .map(this.helper.extractData)
        .catch(this.helper.handleError);
}
```

The above code for binary format, but for excel files you should use this below code:

```
const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'responseType':  'ResponseContentType.Blob',
      'Content-Type':  'application/vnd.ms-excel'})};

  createExcelDocument(model: BillList[]): any {
    return this.http.post(this.getBarBillsUrl + "/CreateExcelDocument", 
            model, httpOptions )
        .map(this.helper.extractData)
        .catch(this.helper.handleError);
}
```

Comment: I could kiss you. It returned a blob after i added the response type in the first block. Please see edited code for handling after that if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

Your "return ms.ToArray();" line needs to move inside the using and possibly add "document.Close();":

```
public byte[] createExcelSpreadsheet(List<BarBillList> barBillExport)
{
    DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(ms, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
        {
            //Creating the initial document
            ...

            //Styling the doucment
            ...

            //Adding width to the columns
            ...

            //Creating the worksheet part to add the data to
            ...

            SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(new SheetData());

            //Creating the first Header Row
            ...

            //Appending the data into their respective columns 
            foreach (var ent in barBillExport)
            {
                ...
            }

            worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
            document.Close();
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gave that a bash, not much luck. Thanks for the attempt.

Comment: @sparemesomecode `ms.ToArray() is already inside the `using` block. If it weren't it would throw an ObjectDisposedException